# datetimepicker edit active date dp.show

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need:

[image: UI Glitch in ListView]

I have tried the code below...

```
$('.date1').datetimepicker({
                    language: 'ru',
                    pickTime: false,
                    useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.show', function() {

});
```

today: 26.11.2017

Default empty input when I open calendar, active date 26.11.2017 and input is empty

I want to change the date to my (05.11.2017) if input is empty
and show active date of input, if input NOT empty

Comment: Have you tried `defaultDate:dateNow` where you can pass `dateNow` as whatever date you want.

Comment: if add defaultDate, this value falls into input. BUT input must be empty

Answer (score 1):

This can be done first removing the `active` class which is the one that define the day selected.

**Note:** As you haven't shown any HTML structure I will guess you're using the structure of the minimum setup

```
$('.date1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'ru',
  pickTime: false,
  useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.show', function() {
  if ($('.date1 :input').val().length === 0) {
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $('[data-day="05.11.2017"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

So what we do is check if our input is empty, If it is then we remove the active day of the by default current day and add our own the `[data-day="05.11.2017"]` is defined by the format or locale that you have setted so if it was the default English, i.e, It would be `[data-day="11/20/2017"]`

To summarize here a live example.

**Note:** It seems like you're using an older version of the library, it shouldn't change the result of the script, I really recommend you to update it.

**Note 2:** The fiddle use the latest version just for the record.

```js
$('.date1').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'ru',
  useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.show', function() {
  if ($('.date1 :input').val().length === 0) {
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $('[data-day="05.11.2017"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/25c11d79/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br/>
<!--Space for the fiddle-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date date1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And, just to help, you can do this: `$('[data-day="' +  dateValue + '"]').addClass('active');` (where `var dateValue = 5/22/2019`). Thanks @William-H-M